# Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#, guid, uniqueidentifier

I get the following error Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Guid'.

However I am sure both of them are of type Guid...

```
public string getOuderEmailAdress(Guid kindid)
        {

            var result = (from a in dc.TOUD_KINs join b in dc.TOUDs on a.fkOuderId equals b.Ouderid where a.fkKindId == kindid select b.Email).Single();
            return result;
        }



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Guid id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);

            if (id != null)
            {
                //Response.Write("id is ");
                Session["id"] = id;


                email = Ouder.getOuderEmailAdress((id));
            }
        }
```

Also in the database there both uniqueidentifiers

Comment: How is `dc` defined? could you show us the class declaration for it?

Comment: Why don't just cast your value?

Comment: You believe one thing. The compiler believes another. Which do you suppose is correct?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, you've just told a story. You wrote some code, its wrong, you got an error. What's your question?

Comment: DC is defined as DAL.VindjekindjeDataContext dc = new DAL.VindjekindjeDataContext();

I am not sure if its a good idea to cast, because a guid id completely different from an int.

fkKindId = the foreign key of KindId ('childId') in my Toud/Kin table which is the table that links my parent table and child table together.

Haha, yes Eric and he's probably correct:)

Comment: Well Eric my question would be that I don't understand why the compiler complains about this error if both data types are the same.

Comment: @Jochem: They're not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "both" when you say they are both uniqueidentifiers, but I would take a look at dc.TOUD_KINs fkKindId field. It looks like that field might be saved in the database as an int. That's the only reason I can imagine you'd get this error.

Comment: Yea because I thought this error was strange considering they are both the same type in my Database, which is uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework or something similar? Do your generated classes have the correct data type for fkKindId?

Comment: Yes, I made sure that the types are consistent in the tables I added into my dbml file.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then, except that the int? error is characteristic of a nullable int column being compared to a guid.

Comment: I know what I did wrong, Sorry to waste all of your time I am a beginner... I altered the database tables in SQL server management studio, and assumed that he would dynamically adjust the tables in my .dbml file... sorry again....

Comment: No worries, that's definitely happened to me when I first started using Entity Framework. You gotta learn somehow :-)